# Add labels to tikzpicture plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do you add labels like `A` and `B` to the two plots below?

[image]

I tried some variations of `\node (A) at ([xshift=-1.3cm, yshift=1cm]group c1r1.north west) {\color{black} (A)};`, but this didn't work, mainly because I am not using a group plots environment.  Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-3.5cm}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    title={My title},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xlabel={x-label},
    ylabel={y-label}]


\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{1.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    title={My title},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xlabel={x-label},
    ylabel={y-label}]
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add name=border (for example) to the axis environment, then you can use \node[above] at (border.north) {A}.  Usually people use a  \caption or \captionof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put `A` and `B` at the upper right corner of the plots?

Then the node `current bounding box` can be used. This method works independently from package `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-3.5cm}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={My title},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xlabel={x-label},
    ylabel={y-label}]
\end{axis}
  \node[below right]
    at (current bounding box.north west) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{1.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={My title},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xlabel={x-label},
    ylabel={y-label}]
\end{axis}
  \node[below right]
    at (current bounding box.north west) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: +1 Thank you!  Good to see that there is an independent method to `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 1):

I put the node above and and the subcaption below.

I take it you realize your figure exceeds the margins.  I made a few changes to center things better.  It helps to put an \fbox around the minipage while adjusting sizes.

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph, subcaption}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-3.5cm}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr .5\textwidth + 3.5cm}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    title={My title},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xlabel={x-label},
    ylabel={y-label},
    name=border]
\end{axis} 
\node[above=1cm] at (border.north) {A above};
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{below}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr .5\textwidth + 3.5cm}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    title={My title},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xlabel={x-label},
    ylabel={y-label},
    name=border]
\end{axis} 
\node[above=1cm] at (border.north) {B above};
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{below}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{-3.5cm}
\textbf{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: captioned tikzpictures]

Comment: `Package pgf Error: No shape named border is known`  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you copy my code or edit your code?  Have you up[dated your packages lately?